# Polymer iron-list not updating view on dynamic add

Tags: javascript, angular, polymer

I am using Polymer 1.7.0 and Angular2 to build a app. I created a custom Polymer element to wrap the iron-list template in order to be able to use it with Angular2 but i have a problem when it comes to dynamicly adding items to the iron-list.

The add function modifies the items array but it doesnt render the new element even if i am triggering the iron-resize event after modifying the items array.

If i delete a item first, and then try to add a element, then it gets rendered.

This is the polymer element i use:

```
<!--.... dependencies imports .... -->
<dom-module id="role-users-list">
  <template>
    <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment custom-layout-classes">
     :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" on-query-matches-changed="queryValueChanged" query-matches="{{wide}}"></iron-media-query>
    <iron-list items="{{items}}" class="test" style="height:85%">
        <template>
            <paper-card class="verticalJustified"> 
            <div class="horizontalJustified">
                <div class="card-content horizontalJustified">
                  <paper-icon-button class="cardIcons" icon="group-work"></paper-icon-button>
                  <div class="verticalStart">
                      <span class="cardTitle">{{item.fullName}}</span>
                      <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.direct}}">
                        <span class="cardSubTitle">User associated directly </span>
                      </template>
                      <template is="dom-if" if="{{!item.direct}}">
                        <span class="cardSubTitle">Role granted through {{item.groupName}} </span>  
                      </template>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.direct}}">
                  <div class="horizontalJustified"> 
                      <paper-icon-button class="cardIcons" icon="delete" target-user="{{item.username}}" on-tap="onDelete" (click)="deleteUser(user)"></paper-icon-button>
                  </div>
                </template>
            </div>
            </paper-card>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'role-users-list',
      onDelete: function(e){
        this.fire("deleteTrigger",{data:e.model.item});
      },
      queryValueChanged: function(e){
        this.fire("mediaQueryTrigger",{data: e.detail.value})
      },
      updateIronList:function(){
        this._nodes.filter(function(value){return value.localName === "iron-list"})[0].fire("iron-resize");
      },
      focusElem:function(){
        var test = this._nodes.filter(function(value){return value.localName === "iron-list"})[0];
        test.selectItem(this.items[0]);
      },
      properties: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          value:[],
        }
       }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

After adding or removing a element i call the updateIronList function to trigger the rendering with the iron-resize event.

PS: The add functionality is in the parent Angular2 component where i modify the items array.

The only difference i could notice was that since the delete button is inside the polymer custom element, it causes it to focus that item when its clicked.

If i didnt make myself understood, ask and i will clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by updating the updateIronList function to:

```
updateIronList:function(){
        let ironListElem = this._nodes.filter(function(value){return value.localName === "iron-list"})[0];
        ironListElem.fire("iron-resize");
        ironListElem._virtualCount = (this.items.length <= 20) ? this.items.length : 20; 
      },
```

It seems the issue was caused by the fact that when the items array length changed, iron-list didnt automaticly update the number of items displayed.